# add alpha video on top of a video in ios

Tags: ios, video

I have found this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos). But it only shows using CALayer to add image. CALayer is only for static component(correct me if I am wrong).

I wish to add an alpha video on top of my record video instead. Is it possible?

Can anyone share the link on how to do it on ios?

Edit:
I found that [iOS developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_Editing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH8-SW1) only mention to merge video. (Put video1 at beginning and video2 at the end) but never mention of adding a video on top of another. So does that mean this is impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution to put 2 video together. Just did same as the merge video example provide by ios developer. But change the starting time of the 2 videos at kCMTimeZero.

This will render two video beginning at the same time. Now just have to find a way to make the video become alpha.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to make the alpha channel work with overlaid videos?

Comment: Yes, please refer to this [link](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post4_h_264_video_with_an_alpha_channel/index.html). You need to change the overlay video become alpha using the method mention in the post. Then replace the background with your video.